# Mutually exclusive contiguous ranges from multiple bitfields

Tags: c++, range, bit-fields

(This is not a CS class homework, even if it looks like one)

I'm using bitfields to represent ranges between 0 and 22. As an input, I have several different ranges, for example (order doesn't matter). I used `.` for `0` and `X` for `1` for better readability.

```
.....XXXXX..............
..XXXX..................
.....XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX....
........XXXXXXX.........
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

The number of bitfield ranges is typically below 10, but can potentially become as high as 100. From that input, I want to calculate the mutually exclusive, contiguous ranges, like this:

```
XX......................
..XXX...................
.....X..................
......XX................
........XX..............
..........XXXXX.........
...............XXXXX....
....................XXXX
```

(again, the output order doesn't matter, they just need to be mutually exclusive and contiguous, i.e. they can't have holes in them. `.....XXX.......XXXXX....` must be split up in two individual ranges).

I tried a couple of algorithms, but all of them ended up being rather complex and unelegant. What would help me immensely is a way to detect that `.....XXX.......XXXXX....` has a hole and a way to determine the index of one of the bits in the hole.

**Edit:** The bitfield range represent zoomlevels on a map. They are intended to be used for outputting XML stylesheets for Mapnik (the tile rendering system that is, among others, used by OpenStreetMap).

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about how you're trying to partition the bits into ranges?  I'd love to help, but I don't quite follow how you came up with the ranges in your example.

Comment: I'll up vote the question because you sparked my curiosity.  Are you inclined to share what this is use for?

Comment: The way I came to the desired solution is approximately as follows: Take a vertical column and compare it with the next one, if it's the same in all rows, it's still within the previous columns range. If at least one item differs, a new range begins. The problem is that the input could potentially have 100 or so rows.

Comment: Agree with xelco52, the problem sounds interesting to me, but I could not get it fully. I see the first block with 5 bitfields (the 5th has all 1's) each of width 22. How does the 'mutually exclusive, contiguous ranges" transformation happen to arrive at the second block of 8 bitfields each of width 22?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the solution you're mentioning in the comment is something like this:

Start at the left or right (so index = 0), and scan which bits are set (upto 100 operations).  Name that set x. Also set a variable block=0.

At index=1, repeat and store to set y. If x XOR y = 0, both are identical sets, so move on to index=2.  If it x XOR y = z != 0, then range [block, index) is contiguous.  Now set x = y, block = index, and continue.

If you have 100 bit-arrays of length 22 each, this takes something on the order of 2200 operations.

This is an optimum solution because the operation cannot be reduced further -- at each stage, your range is broken if another set doesn't match your set, so to check if the range is broken you must check all 100 bits.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a shot at your sub-problem, at least..

> What would help me immensely is a way to detect that
>   `.....XXX.......XXXXX....` has a hole and a way to determine the index
>   of one of the bits in the hole.

Finding the lowest and highest set ("1") bits in a bitmask is a pretty
solved problem; See, for example, `ffs(3)` in glibc, or see
e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array#Find_first_one

Given the first and last indexes of a bitmap, call them `i`, and `j`,
you can compute the bitmap that has all bits betweem `i` and `j` set
using `M = ((1 << i) - 1) & (~((1 << j) - 1))` (apologies for any
off-by-one-errors).

You can then test if the original bitmap has a hole by comparing it to
`M`. If it doesn't match, you can take the input xor `M` to find the
holes and repeat.